# Laravel - How can i alter an existing referenced column and make it a foreign key column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So in my migration file i have referenced some columns like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
    });
}
```

The issue is that in my code i can access the relationship between the models like this: `product->category` and it works perfectly fine. However, in the database i just seen that the column does not show as a foreign key, and its not indexed. Also my datbase software doesnt show the Relationship between the different tables.

So my questions are:

1. How could i solve this, and make the column foreign key and indexed without having major impacts on my code. The code is also live in production as well.
2. Why does my current code work, even though the foreign key isnt there?
3. After making the foreign key column change is there anything else in my code i will have to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your migration needs to exist of 2 lines, try out the following syntax:

```php
// Create the column.
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
// Create the foreign key relation.
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints